# SQLite Qt auto_incremet column is always null

Tags: qt, sqlite

My app check for the existence of a db file, and if it doesn't exist it creates one

One of the tables is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tAlumnos ( Nombre     VARCHAR (100),
                        Apellido   VARCHAR (100),
                        DNI        INT UNIQUE,
                        Nacimiento DATE,
                        Telefono   INT,
                        ICE        INT,
                        keyid      INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        PRIMARY KEY (keyid) );
```

However when I add serveral rows with queries like this:

```
INSERT INTO tAlumnos (Nombre,Apellido,DNI,Nacimiento,Telefono) VALUES ('Pepe','pepe','20369458','2010-05-02','154222326');
```

All the keyid's column are null. I don't get it. What am I doing wrong.
Also I get a syntax error if I use AUTOINCREMENT instead of AUTO_INCREMENT, in case that matters.

When I open the DB I do it like this:

```
     db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
     db.setDatabaseName(DBFILE);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong keyword, the keyword is **AUTOINCREMENT**. However, that is not the only issue as such. The `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword can only be used in one situation and that is for a column that is to be an alias of the **rowid**. For a column to be an alias of the **rowid**,

1. the table must not be defined with the `WITHOUT ROWID` (use of `WITHOUT ROWID` is not very common) and
2. **the column must be declared as `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (or as `?? INTEGER, ..and other column definitions.., PRIMARY KEY(??)` (where `??` represents the column name).**

`AUTOINCREMENT` can then either be used as `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` or `?? INTEGER, ..and other subsequent column definitions if any.., PRIMARY KEY(?? AUTOINCREMENT)`

Defining the column as `keyid INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT` will result in the column type being `INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT` (which will result in a type affinity of INTEGER) and thus when no value is supplied, with the expectation that an auto generated value will be supplied, the default value of null is the result.

[Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

As such your code could be :-

```
CREATE TABLE tAlumnos ( Nombre     VARCHAR (100),
                        Apellido   VARCHAR (100),
                        DNI        INT UNIQUE,
                        Nacimiento DATE,
                        Telefono   INT,
                        ICE        INT,
                        keyid      INTEGER,
                        PRIMARY KEY (keyid AUTOINCREMENT) );
```

or :-

```
CREATE TABLE tAlumnos ( Nombre     VARCHAR (100),
                        Apellido   VARCHAR (100),
                        DNI        INT UNIQUE,
                        Nacimiento DATE,
                        Telefono   INT,
                        ICE        INT,
                        keyid      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);
```

## However

The `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword is very likely not needed and you would perhaps not want the associated overheads (see link below).

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.

[SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Not using the keyword and instead using `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `?? INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(??)` will still automatically generate a unqiue id (i.e. the column will be an alias of the **rowid**) if no value or null is supplied as the value when inserting, without the overheads.

`AUTOINCREMENT` only ensures that the rowid will always increase (noting that there is no guarantee that the rowid 
 will increase monotonically).

Not using `AUTOINCREMENT` allows unused/free numbers that are less than the existing highest rowid to be used, should the highest possible number be used (`AUTOINCREMENT` would instead fail with an SQLITE_FULL exception). Note that **rowid**, and thus an alias, can be as high as 9223372036854775807.

- (see link above for a fully comprehensive explanation)

As such you may wish to use either :-

```
CREATE TABLE tAlumnos ( Nombre     VARCHAR (100),
                        Apellido   VARCHAR (100),
                        DNI        INT UNIQUE,
                        Nacimiento DATE,
                        Telefono   INT,
                        ICE        INT,
                        keyid      INTEGER,
                        PRIMARY KEY (keyid) );
```

or :-

```
CREATE TABLE tAlumnos ( Nombre     VARCHAR (100),
                        Apellido   VARCHAR (100),
                        DNI        INT UNIQUE,
                        Nacimiento DATE,
                        Telefono   INT,
                        ICE        INT,
                        keyid      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
```

Comment: Thank you for this complete and informative answers. I copied my code from one of my older sql scripts that creates tables in a MySQL DB. It seems that some things change in SQLite.